# how does javascript know which button I'm pressing?

Tags: javascript, button, foreach

```
  function render(ourCart) {
    ourCart.forEach(function(item) {
      const renderCart = document.createElement('div');
      renderCart.innerText = item.name + ' $' + item.price;
      cart.appendChild(renderCart);
      const addButton = document.createElement('button');
      addButton.innerText = 'Add';
      renderCart.appendChild(addButton);
      renderCart.onclick = function() {
        total = total + (+item.price);
        console.log(item.name);
        console.log(item.price); 
      }
    })
  }
```

this function is supposed to render the name and price of a product and also an 'add' button that adds up the prices of all the products. After a lot of trying I decided to look up the solution which uses '.onclick = function () {}' inside the forEach loop as shown in the screenshot.

[render output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zFxQZ.png)
this works perfectly fine. I can press the button next to 'apple' twice for example and console.log(total) gives me 3*2 = 6. But, my question is how does javascript know that I'm pressing the button next to apple and not egg? I'm not using any id here to give each button a specific function or anything. The forEach loop goes over all the objects in the array and goes over the .onclick = function() thing twice in this case (two objects in my example array). Does this store a temporary value in the onclick function or something? Any help is appreciated!

Comment: Please write your code in the question and don't post image links.

Comment: You create a div element for each item in the array and at the same time set an onclick for it. That is how it knows.